# 配列の変換前と変換後が同じになる

Tags: ruby

```
a=[[1,2],[]]
b=Array.new(a)
b[1].push(b[0].pop)
```

としてaを変更前bを変更後としたいのに
どちらも[[1],[2]]となる
私の間違い？rubyの間違い？

Answer (score 4):

[Array.new](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/1.8.7/method/Array/s/new.html)から引用

> 指定された配列 ary を複製して返します。 Array#dup 同様 要素を複製しない浅い複製です。

ということで、Array.new(配列)で作成した要素は元のオブジェクトと同じもの(同じものを参照している)です。
いわゆる浅いコピー（シャローコピー）です。

参照：[深いコピーと浅いコピー](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Object/i/clone.html)

Comment: 質問を編集変更しました。深いコピー